# How to use SSL with prisma on a vercel deployment

Tags: node.js, database, ssl, prisma, vercel

I have a NodeJS application that uses Prisma ORM to connect to a database that enforces SSL connections. The prisma client is configured to read the connection-string from an environment variable. During build the provided certificates get purged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the issues

- https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4324
- https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1673

it is not trivial to accomplish that. You can store the certificate in a folder your server will serve as the static assets folder to avoid the purging but its internal path won't be visible.

You should let your connection-string's `sslcert` parameter point to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` as decribed here:

- https://davidparks.dev/blog/planetscale-deployment-with-prisma/